# Positional error when trying to specify member

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to get a member name rather than the author name

I've tried a few methods like `for member is message.server.members:` which returned multiple results with every member in the server and tried  `member: discord.Member` as a signature which produced an error:

Heres what I'm working with:

```
async def on_message_delete(self, message):
    server = message.server
    author = message.author
    role =  get(server.roles, name="Powerbot")
    channel = get(message.server.channels, name="mod-log")
    time = datetime.utcnow()
    cleanmsg = message.content
    for i in message.mentions:
        cleanmsg = cleanmsg.replace(i.mention, str(i))
    fmt = '%H:%M:%S'
    name = author
    name = " ~ ".join((name.name, name.nick)) if name.nick else name.name
    if role not in author.roles:
        infomessage = "A message by {}, was deleted in {} by {}".format(message.author.mention, message.channel.mention, member,mention)
        delmessage = discord.Embed(description=infomessage, colour=discord.Color.purple(), timestamp=time)
        delmessage.add_field(name="Message:", value=cleanmsg)
        delmessage.set_footer(text="User ID: {}".format(message.author.id))
        delmessage.set_author(name=name + " message deleted.", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        delmessage.set_thumbnail(url="http://i.imgur.com/fJpAFgN.png")
        try:
            await self.bot.send_message(channel, embed=delmessage)
        except:
            pass
```

The line specifically where member.mention is.

`infomessage = "A message by {}, was deleted in {} by {}".format(message.author.mention, message.channel.mention, member.mention)`

Example output: A message by author was deleted in channel by member.

If anyone could help that would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `TypeError: on_message_delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'`  that is the message I get if I add `member: discord.Member` to the coroutine signature.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing the person who deleted the message is not possible from the discord release that you’re using, since the stable discord.py does not contain support for audit logs. **You will need discord.py rewrite** to use the following solution:

```
@bot.event()
async def on_message_delete(msg):
    audits = await msg.guild.audit_logs(limit=10, action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete)
    async for audit in audits:
        try:
            await audit.target.get_message(msg.id)
        except discord.NotFound:
            continue      
        print(audit.user)
        break
```

That’s under the assumption that messages are kept even after being deleted. If the above does not work, I guess the best we can do is:

```
@bot.event()
async def on_message_delete(msg):
    audits = await msg.guild.audit_logs(limit=10, action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete)
    audit = await audits.get(extra__channel=msg.channel)
    print(audit.user)
```

For further information, see:

https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/audit-log

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.AuditLogAction

Comment: I might’ve made a typo or two in the code sample since I’m on mobile (can’t verify). It’ll be great if someone can point out anything wrong with the code or if it works. Thanks!

Comment: [According to the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete), `target` is the `User` or `Member` who had their message deleted, not the message itself.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I mistakenly thought it was the Message, it would make a lot more sense that way. Don’t know why they set target to a Member.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the client isn't informed about who deleted the message, just the fact that it was deleted.  The `message` object itself doesn't hold that information, and the [`RawMessageDeleteEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.RawMessageDeleteEvent) from the rewrite branch doesn't have it either.

I'm not super familiar with the underlying Discord API, but the [`Message Delete`](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#message-delete) gateway event looks to be what `discord.py` receives when a message is deleted, and it doesn't mention anything about the identity of the deleter.