# Discord bot check if a bot deleted a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make my discord bot to send a reply message only if a user has deleted a message (not bots). I'm using `message.author.bot` to find out, but it seems that deleting messages isn't the same. So far I have this:

```python3
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
  if message.author.bot:
    return
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "<@{}>'s message was deleted".format(message.author.id))
```

Comment: I'm unsure based on your wording whether you want to exclude messages of a bot that were deleted or messages that were deleted by a bot. Could you clarify your intentions?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527482/positional-error-when-trying-to-specify-member/52531478#52531478).  Depending on your version, you may not be able to see who deleted a message.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks. It seems that the discord API doesn't show who deleted the message. Maybe this question is unsolvable.

Comment: Best you can do is give the bot permission to check the audit logs, then look for the message's deletion in there (as in that answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is the answer to your question

```py
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message, member):
    if message.author.id == client.user.id): #Checks the ID, if AuthorID = BotID, return. Else, continue.
        author : message.author #Defines the message author
        content : message.content #Defines the message content
        channel : message.channel #Defines the message channel
        logchannel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='<XYZ>') #Defines the logs channel
        await logchannel.send(channel, '{}: {}'.format(author, content)) #Send the message.
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Comment: `author : message.author` is an annotation indicating that `author` has type `message.author`.  You probably want `author = message.author`